# How to handle nested scrollings in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview

I'm trying to achieve this structure:

- SlidingUpPanel

  - Body (app background)
  - Sliding panel, as a PageView

    - Pages, as a Column

      - A title (not scrollable inside the page)
      - A ListView (scrollable)

        - some list items

Expectations are:

- if the user scrolls on a Page, outside the ListView (e.g. on the title), then the panel slides
- if the user scrolls on a Page, inside the ListView:

  - if the List is at its limit (impossible to scroll the list any more), then the panel slides
  - else the list scrolls

I tried to attach the scrollController from the panel to the listView, or not.
Both solutions don't work:

- With the same controller, I get an Exception: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
- With another controller for the listView (that is one controller per page), behavior doesn't meet the expectations: the panel and the listview scroll simultaneously, even if the list's limit is not reached.

Here is a code example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel2/sliding_up_panel2.dart';

class ScrollsTestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ScrollsTestScreen({super.key});

  final PanelController panelController = PanelController();
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: SlidingUpPanel(
        body: const Center(child: Text("body")),
        controller: panelController,
        maxHeight: 670,
        minHeight: 110,
        scrollController: scrollController,
        panelBuilder: () => PageView(children: [
          Page(
            title: "First page",
            length: 6,
            scrollController: scrollController,
          ),
          Page(
            title: "Second page",
            length: 20,
            scrollController: scrollController,
          ),
          Page(
            title: "Third page",
            length: 60,
            scrollController: scrollController,
          ),
        ]),
        color: Colors.white24,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final int length;
  final ScrollController scrollController;
  const Page({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.length,
    required this.scrollController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 120,
          child: Text(title),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            primary: false,
            controller: scrollController, // Or also tried ScrollController(),
            itemCount: length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
              title: Text("Item $index"),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

*As a side note, I'm using the sliding_up_panel2 package as it's quite handy - some methods allow to get the opened/closed status of the panel, and to open/close it programmatically.*

*I'm opened to alternatives if this may solve the issue.*

Thanks!!!

Comment: Tentatively, I'd say look into Flutter Slivers.